# problems with bluetooth string received

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to receive a Bluetooth message from a digital balance
i do it like

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread
{
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocketWrapper socket)
    {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try
        {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try{
            int bytes;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int availableBytes = mmInStream.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[availableBytes];
                    if (availableBytes > 0){
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                        String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        // Envia los datos obtenidos hacia el evento via handler
                        int finalBytes = bytes;

                        if (bytes>=3){
                            bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, finalBytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                        }else{
                            SystemClock.sleep(100);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception er){
            er.printStackTrace();
        }



        // Se mantiene en modo escucha para determinar el ingreso de datos

    }
```

my problem is at the message that i receive.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRJLX.png)

at the image you'll can see a green mark,  that's the entire message that i should receive, but sometimes comes just the weight or nothing, i connect with another app to the digital balance and the message come complete. so the balance is not the problem i think.

thanks for reading and the help. goodbye

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a commercial scale, and thus the protocol details are outside your control. Nevertheless, as suggested in @iosif-bancioiu's answer, there is probably a token in the binary that delineates the message boundaries, and you're just not seeing it because of the way you're dumping the data. (Or, the token is "ST". Who knows?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a 'token' in order to let the android side know that the command / string ended. for example: when sending a command to andorid myString, send it as myString\r\n and parse it on your android device. The issue that you have seems to be related to the Bluetooth device / module buffer not being flushed